# parallelism and puncturing in Turbo Codes

Tags: error-correction

I understand that puncturing is the deletion of certain bits in the encoder output according to a matrix, but I am having trouble understanding the benefit of this. Does this just provide better way of overlaying the data to decode it? And if bits are deleted how exactly is it recovered?

Similarly, I am having trouble understanding parallelism. My current understanding is that it is kind of like diversity combining and multiplexing. How exactly is it different?

I have asked both questions under the same post because they are both concepts involved with Turbo codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puncturing is simply not transmitting some code bits. This reduces the bandwidth overhead of the code, but it also reduces the code's effectiveness as the removed bits can't be recovered at the other end and as such can't be used to aid in decoding. The point is to be able to trade overhead for error correcting ability without having to completely change the coding technique.

Comment: If it is deleted, won't this cause a shift in the remaining packet, making the decoding process impossible as there is no proper decoding method for deletion channels? Unless of course, the decoder knows exactly what positions the bits were deleted.

Comment: Obviously the transmitter and receiver have to agree on what bits to remove. This can be baked in to the spec though, perhaps defining a couple of different rates. Also, the parity bits don't have to be sent interleaved with the data, in a number of cases they are sent in a block at the end.